# SQL Query to update duplicate records which were transmitted earlier

Tags: sql, sql-server

Request someone to help on below issue with sql server query. I want to update **remarks column** as per below table. Currently I am updating **remarks column** as **"Duplicate record found"** but now I want to add **value date** as well which were transmitted earlier.

```
ID  RefNo       Value Date  Remarks
1   MFX93838    20-05-2020
2   MFX93838    25-05-2020  Record is already transmitted on 20-05-2020
3   MOU93838    22-05-2020   
4   MOU93838    23-05-2020  Record is already transmitted on 22-05-2020
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`.  For an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, lag(date) over (partition by refno order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set remarks = concat('Record is already transmitted on ', prev_date)
    where prev_date is not null;
```

You might want to use `convert()` or `format()` to put the date into a particular format.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon Linoff